# Is it possible for cuda threads to have local/private copy of an argument which can be updated without affecting the other

Tags: cuda

I have come across a situation whereby I need to provide a number of arrays as input to a global function,  I need each thread to be able to perform operations on the array  in such a manner that they will not affect how others threads copy of the array, I provide the below code as an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
__global__ void testLocalCopy(double *temper){

     int threadIDx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; 

     // what I need is for each thread to set temper[3] to its id without affecting any other threads copy
    // so thread id 0 will have a set its copy of temper[3] to 0 and thread id 3 will set it to 3 etc.
     temper[3]=threadIDx;
     printf("For thread  %d  the val in temper[3] is   %lf \n",threadIDx,temper[3]);

}
```

just to restate , Is there a method whereby a given thread can be certain that no other thread is updating its value of temper[3] ?

I initially believed I would be able to solve this problem by using constant memory, but as constant memory is readonly this did not meet my needs,

I am using cuda 4.0 , please see the main function below.

```
int main(){

    double temper[4]={2.0,25.9999,55.3,66.6};
double *dev_temper;
int size=4;


    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_temper, size * sizeof(double) );
cudaMemcpy( dev_temper, &temper, size * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );


testLocalCopy<<<2,2>>>(dev_temper);
cudaDeviceReset();

cudaFree(dev_temper);

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Connor

Comment: You have vast amount of memory and you may use 2D arrays of one dimension (y dimension) is equal to the number of threads?

Comment: May I ask, why do you need this?

Comment: The program I'm trying to speed up takes as parameters 4 arguments each of which hold 3600 doubles,  it uses these arguments and others arguments to calculate a result, if each thread holds a local copy , I thought I might be able to reduce the values I have to cudamalloc and cudamemcpu,

Comment: I did get malloc working inside the kernel and could memcpy the values down from the argument, I'll keep working on it and let you know, what worked out best for me.  I know for at least one area of the problem I'm working on I'll have to use 2d arrays, thanks

Comment: memcpy/malloc inside a kernel is likely to be very inefficient in the vast majority of cases! Inorder to avoid premature optimisation, I recommend memcpy'ing all data via cudamalloc from the CPU before kernel launching. After this, profile the results and then see whether it is better for each thread to manage a local copy of an array.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll use the memcpy/malloc inside the thread for now and I'll use the cudamalloc/cuda memcpu afterwards and I'll let you know which provided the best results,

Answer (score 1):

Within your kernel function you can allocate memory as

> int temper_per_thread[4];

Now each thread will have seperate and unique access to this array within your kernel e.g. the code below will populate `temper_per_thread` with the current thread index:

> temper_per_thread[0]=threadIDx;
>
> temper_per_thread[1]=threadIDx;
>
> temper_per_thread[2]=threadIDx;
>
> temper_per_thread[3]=threadIDx;

Of course if you wish to transfer all these thread specific arrays back to the CPU, you will need a different approach. 1) allocate a larger portion of global memory. 2) The size of this larger portion of global memory will be the number of threads multiplied by the number of elements unique to each thread. 3) Index the array writing such that each thread always writes to unique location within global memory. 4) Do a GPU to CPU memcpy after the kernel finishes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using malloc and memcpy inside a thread for now, I'll let you know,If I can attain the required speedup, thanks for taking the time to answer